# Paypal, 2Checkout IPN received parameters

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, 2checkout

What are the parameters which PAYPAL and 2Checkout  sends for IPN in case for buy without subscription, subscription first payment, subscription not first payment and refund.

I need understand the workflow so I can implement correct. I already checked the documentation and I already build the form for payment with/without subscription.

Comment: This is all [documented](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/notifications/order-created).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full parameter list is located https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/notifications/order-created there for a non-recurring sale, use the sidebar nav on the left to find the recurring INS messages. Each INS link has a description as to when the event is triggered:

> e.g. Order creation is a new order placed online by a buyer. You may want to automate inventory management, fulfillment or setup of login credentials based on this message.
>
> Recurring order creation is a special case of order creation; if any item ordered is recurring, the recurring parameter will be set to 1, otherwise, it will be set to 0.
>
> Please note the initial installment billed often differs in price from the installments due to startup fees.
>
> Order Created is an invoice level message; it will be sent once for each new sale and will contain information about all items ordered.